# Structural induction in ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can ZFC prove everything that ZFC + the axiom schema $\Big[\forall_x [\forall_{y\in x} \phi(y)]\implies \phi(x)\Big] \implies \forall_x \phi(x)$ can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the fact that this axiom schema is in fact equivalent to the Axiom of Regularity (over $\sf ZF-Reg$, that is), yes.

(You probably want to add parameters to $\phi$ for the equivalence, but the parameter-free version is certainly a consequence.)

Comment: Thanks, I looked up regularity on wikipedia and there is a proof https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#Every_set_has_an_ordinal_rank . I don't understand what you mean with the parameters